# My vector can't access an element that exists?

Tags: c++, vector

I create a program that reads data (and return each token), and if a certain value is encountered in the stream, this is replaced by another value or a series of other values.

For example :

```
name: [name]
id:   [ID]
```

Should give:

```
name: Bob
id:   23 87 87 9
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
token lexer::next() {
    token ret;
    if (IsData) {
        if (DataValue.empty()) IsData = false;
        else {
            ret = DataValue.front();
            DataValue.erase(DataValue.begin());
            return ret
        }
    }

    // some code to manage others tokens (a value is also assigned to 'ret')

    if (Datas.IsData(ret.value)) {
        // here, ret.value represent the '[value]' saw above
        DataValue = Datas.get(ret.value);
        IsData = true;
        return next();
    }

    return ret; // for "normal" tokens

}
```

`DataValue` is just a `std::vector<token>`. And each time we return the first element, which is then deleted until there is no more.

When there is only one replacement value, it works. But beyond that I get this error message:

[image]

I don't understand... The only assumption I have is that, since the function cannot return more than one token at a time, it encroaches on the other calls (because de value to replace can count more than 1 token). But I'm not sure.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: Did you do as the message stated and pressed "Retry" to debug?  Visual Studio takes you to the call stack, and in that call stack is your code (and values) that caused the issue.  Also, assuming your program works one way, and then getting a bug is not something strange.  Simply debug your program, fix what you thought was happening but isn't, and go on from there.

Comment: It is obvious. You try to access a vector element by  an index that ecceeds the vector size minus 1. It's time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Turn on all warnings. `if (Datas.IsData(ret.value))` can be reached with no prior assignment to `ret`.

Comment: Use `std::deque` instead of `std::vector`. It's much more efficient for removing elements from front.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your explanation and your code correctly, it seems that this line is the culprit:

```
DataValue = Datas.get(ret.value);
```

`DataValue` is a vector containing many multiple elements; you've removed the first one (with `.erase(DataValue.begin())`), you should now be inserting one in its stead.

However - it's difficult to say for sure what the problem is, since you have not provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

PS - Note it is usually inefficient to remove the first element of a vector and add a different first element - you'll be moving the entire vector's context repeatedly.